# Why can the struct initializer be used after initialization but not the array one?

Tags: arrays, c, struct

Struct initializes can be used after initialization by casting it. Eg.

```
struct EST {
    int a;
    float b;
}est;

int main() {
    est = (struct EST){23, 45.4}; //This works nicely and est gets the values
    printf("a: %d\nb: %f\n", est.a, est.b);
}
```

But the same can't be done for arrays:

```
int arr[6];
arr = (int []){1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

This gives

> error: assignment to expression with array type

What's more head breaking is that if there is an array in the struct, it still works.

```
struct Weird {
    int arr[6];
}w;

int main() {
    w = (struct Weird){{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}; /* It works. The member arr gets all its elements
filled
*/
}
```

There seems to be something about the `=` operator not being valid with arrays after initializing. That is my theory.

Why is this and how can arrays be assigned  after initializing?

Comment: C supports structure assignment, but not array assignment.  Note that array initialization is not the same as array assignment.

Comment: @TomKarzes Okay then. What are the differences?

Comment: Initialization is an initial value specified as part of a variable declaration.  Assignment is assignment of a value to a previously declared variable.  For example, `int a = 5;` is a declaration of `a` that includes an initialization, while `a = 5;` is an assignment to `a`, which must have been previously declared.

Comment: Because "An array is not a lvalue..."

Answer (score 1):

initialization means initializing of a variable at declaration time. The following is correct and is supported by 'c':

```
int arr[6] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
```

Assignment means assigning a value to a variable somwhere in the program after initialization. 'C' does not support assignment to a whole array. Arrays are very special members in 'c' and are treated in a special way which does not allow assignments.

However, you can always copy one array into another either by using a for loop or my using something like `memcpy`. Here is an example:

```
  int arr[6], brr[6] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
  memcpy(arr,(int[6]){1,2,3,4,5},sizeof(int[6]));
```

BTW, the cast-like object from your example `(int[]){1,2,3,4,5}` is called 'compound literal' and is also allowed in c. Here it is used to *initialize* the parameter of the memcpy function.